# Stop TextView from truncating whole words

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to replace `android:singleLine="true"` with `android:maxLines="1"` since it's deprecated. Naturally it didn't go as planned and here's my problem:

If I have a string

```
String s = "this is a sample"
```

and use `singleLine="true"` I get something like:

```
     (View)
+-------------+
|this is a sam|
+-------------+
```

however using `maxlines="1"` I now get:

```
     (View)
+-------------+
|this is a    |
+-------------+
```

(in both versions I'm using `ellipsize="none"`)
Since `sample` does not fit, it's completely removed instead of truncated. The problem is that I really need to jam as much text in as possible, it doesn't matter that it's cropped in a middle of the a word. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: check textView [autosizing](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that's what you want to do.

In layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="this is a sample"
    tools:ignore="TextViewEdits"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="this is a sample"/>
```

And result of this code:

[image: Result]

Comment: Setting `android:inputType="text"` was the part that fixed the issue, not sure yet if there are other consequences.